# Prettify.JS does not display HTML script tags properly

Tags: javascript, regex, prettify

I'm using Prettify.JS to display some code on a Web site I'm developing. I seem to be having some problems with script tags, especially 'non-linking' ones:

```
<pre>
// Link CSS
&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;device.css&quot; /&gt;

// Link JQuery
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;jquery-1.7.1.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;

// Link DeviceJS
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;device.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;

// Initialize DeviceJS
&lt;script&gt;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('selector').devicejs(options);
    });
&lt;/script&gt;
</pre>
```

This code displays the following (notice the entire script tag is red):

[image: Prettify Code]

However, when I do this little hack below (adding some invisible html before closing the opening script tag):

```
<pre>
// Link CSS
&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;device.css&quot; /&gt;

// Link JQuery
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;jquery-1.7.1.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;

// Link DeviceJS
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;device.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;

// Initialize DeviceJS
&lt;script<span style="display:none;"> t</span>&gt;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('selector').devicejs(options);
    });
&lt;/script&gt;
</pre>
```

It seems to display Ok:

[image: Prettify Code after hack]

The problem is when I add multiple non-linked script tag blocks, The problem comes up again. So the following code:

```
<pre>
// Link CSS
&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;device.css&quot; /&gt;

// Link JQuery
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;jquery-1.7.1.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;

// Link DeviceJS
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;device.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;

// Initialize DeviceJS
&lt;script<span style="display:none;"> t</span>&gt;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('selector').devicejs(options);
    });
&lt;/script&gt;

&lt;script<span style="display:none;"> t</span>&gt;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('selector').devicejs(options);
    });
&lt;/script&gt;
</pre>
```

Shows as:

[image]

I looked through the Prettify.JS Source Code and on line 1211 I see the following:

```
['lang-js',      /^<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)(<\/script\b[^>]*>)/i],
```

which I believe is part of the lexer.

I'm not a Regex Ninja so I would appreciate any assistance on how I could tweak this so that Prettify.JS can accommodate non-linking script tags with no attributes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you prettifying this?  Typically `<pre>` tags have to have `class="prettyprint"` on them, and these don't.  Are you using the programmatic API?  If so, with what language hint?

Comment: Yes, I have that set already. Sorry, I should have added that for clarity

Answer (score 0):

An [HTML](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/prettify_test.html#html) example shows this working fine, so I suspect your problem relates to prettify not recognizing the content as HTML and so using the wrong language handler.  Without seeing how you're invoking prettify, it's hard to say.

---

> I looked through the Prettify.JS Source Code and on line 1211 I see the following:
>
> ```
> ['lang-js',      /^<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)(<\/script\b[^>]*>)/i],
> ```
>
> which I believe is part of the lexer.

You are correct.  This is saying that a script elements starts with

```
<script\b[^>]*>
```

or the text `<script` (case-insensitively due to `/i` at the end) followed by a word break and any number of non `>` characters followed by a `>`

Then

```
([\s\S]*?)
```

non-greedily matches the minimal number of characters necessary before the close tag.  This is in capturing group 1 so this content will be recursively prettified using the type hint `lang-js`.

Finally

```
(<\/script\b[^>]*>)
```

works similarly to the open tag, but is a close tag.  It should probably not be in a capturing group, but that shouldn't affect correctness.

Comment: I'm referring to `<script>` tags. It doesn't work if you have them empty e.g. `<script>`, you have to have `<script type="text/javascript">` or it's going to be like I just described. I'm trying to see if I can update the regex in the lexer to remedy this. If not, I'll just define it with an attribute.

Comment: @ChuckUgwuh, there is nothing in that regex that would prevent it from matching `<script></script>`.  What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version that is on their website at this time: prettify-small-1-Jun-2011.tar.bz2. And I meant something like `<script>\nsome javascript\n</script>`.